# Add google drive editing functionality to sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-designer, development, edit-form

I am trying to upgrate from lotus domino to Sharepoint. I am currently using Domino with files where multiple people can work in the same time at. Like google drive where anyone who can edit the file can work with it in the same time. Since we are moving toward a new system(Sharepoint) I would like to know if this would be still possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Microsoft terms this is called Co-Authoring. You can google this and verify what I have written below.

It has 1 less functionality than google docs (and I do not know why google docs has it and Microsoft doesn't).

You can edit in browser and in client simultaneously Word and Power Point. You can edit simultaneously Excel only in the web application (in the browser).

It has been like that since Co-authoring was introduced in version 2010. It is still like that now in 2013 version.

It probably has to do with the incapability of the platform to manage potentially all the real features of the desktop version of excel while simultaneously opening it for multiple people.